# PayPal Integration into Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, paypal

I am working on a donations web page.  I have created a merchant account with PayPal and have successfully integrated PayPal Checkout into my website.

The only problem is that I want to verify that the user actually made the transaction on PayPal's website.  How can this be done please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on Paypal IPN.
It will post some parameters to a address of your choice where u must handle the POST and reply back. There should be code examples of this on paypal dev site.

Ed.

When user payment is completed PP POST to YourSite.com/PaypalIPN.. here you must process the POST from PP and reply so that PP knows you have received the POST. If you don't do this PP will continue to send payment info.

The PP POST contains stuff like order number, transaction id etc.. wich u can use to process the user order.

Comment: I found the following code sample but could not understand what is going on.

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_ASP_NET_C.txt

Comment: ed. the answer but it's that file you want to use.